# Loading records to a TableView - (More button)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have like 100 records to display on a table. But i will be only displaying 10 records, and when the user clicks the last row `(Which will have a button that will say load the next 10 records)` the table will row the next 10 records.

I have displayed the more button on the last cell successfully. But i don't know how to display 10 records at a time. My code so far;

**ViewDidLoad**

```
self.arrayThatContainsAllHundredRecords= [NSArray arrayWithArray:hundredRecordsArray];

[self performSelector:@selector(addTheTableFooter:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

**addTheTableFooter**

```
UIView* footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];

[footer addSubview:moreButton]; // i have also added an event to the button click see below, and i have not shown it here.

self.tableView.tableFooterView =footer;

[self.mainWindow removeFromSuperview];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

The above would Display the `More` button after displaying all `100` records.

**moreButtonClickAction**

```
-(void)moreButtonClickAction {
NSLog(@"Suppose to load the next 10 records");
}
```

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.arrayThatContainsAllHundredRecords count];
}
```

I need a way to edit this code, so i will only display 10 records at a time, and display the next 10 when the user clicks the `more` button. (Now the total records should be 20 - (previous 10 + the 10 records as a result of clicking the `more` button ))

NOTE: I will be downloading all 100 records and saving it in `self.arrayThatContainsAllHundredRecords` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

I believe that i have to make some change before executing `[self.tableView reloadData];`, as in tell to load 10 records.

Well, say if i only had 53 records. Then the user will click the more button 5 times and on the 6th instance, the table should display only 3 records. How can this be handled in the tableview:numberOfRowsInSection: ?

Comment: Wait, so when the first 10 rows are visible and the user presses the button to show more records, what is visible at that point? The first 20 records, or only records 11-20? In my answer I assumed the former, and MusiGenesis is responding for the latter.

Comment: The 1st 10 records + the 2nd 10 records should be visible. There should be a total of 20 records now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is the method that determines how many rows will be shown, so the first step will be to change that. You also need a property in your view controller to keep track of how many rows should be visible. Something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.numberOfRowsVisible;
}
```

And when the more button is clicked, you have to increase that number and reload the tableView data.

```
-(void)moreButtonClickAction {
    if (self.numberOfRowsVisible < self.maxNumberOfRows) 
        self.numberOfRowsVisible = MIN(self.numberOfRowsVisible + 10, self.maxRows);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I get it. But what will hapen if we have 53 records. We hard coding 10 in the  `moreButtonClickAction` event. When the user clicks for the 6th time there would be an exception. How could we solve this (Sorry i didn't mention this in the question before)

Comment: Initially, when the viewloads it will load with data, So what will `self.numberOfRowsVisible` be ? Are we giving it a value initially ?

Comment: It should be set to 10 initially since you want 10 rows to be visible at first.

Comment: What hapence if the array returns only 4 records. Then i need to display 4 records only. If we set `self.numberOfRowsVisible` to 10 then there might be an error/exception

Comment: Okay, so initially set `self.numberOfRowsVisible` to `MIN(self.maxNumberOfRows, 10)`

Answer (score 1):

To display 10 rows at a time, your `tableview:numberOfRowsInSection:` should return 10 (instead of returning the total number of records in your source array).

Your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should then handle the paging, adding the current page times 10 to the `indexPath.row` property, to determine which element in your source array to use to feed the cell view.

When your "More" button is tapped, you should call `[self.tableView reloadData];` there.

**Edit:** your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TesterCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSInteger dataIndex = indexPath.row + (pageNumber * 10);
    MyDataObject *data = (MyDataObject *)[self.arrayThatContainsAllHundredRecords 
        objectAt:dataIndex];

    NSString *cellText = data.LastName; // or whatever

    cell.textLabel.text = cellText;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Well, say if i only had 53 records. Then the user will click the more button 5 times and on the 6th instance, the table should display only 3 records. How can this be handled in the `tableview:numberOfRowsInSection:` (i didn't mention this in the question - sorry) ? i didn't understand what i should do in the  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` event. Could you please add some detail ?

Comment: from where does `pageNumber` come from ?